# Subspace of a topological space.

Tags: general-topology

Let $(X,\tau)$ be a topological space and $Y\subset X$, then $F$ is a $\tau_{y}$ closed iff $F = Y\cap H$, $H \in \tau^{c}$, is this right or wrong I do not know even how to think, could anyone discuss this with me please?

Comment: It is right and the rule determines the subspace topology on $Y$.

Comment: Life is hard if you don't even know how to think

Comment: The answers given seem to cover it. Observe also that when $A\subset Y,$ the closure of $A$ in the subspace $Y,$ denoted $Cl_Y(A) ,$ is equal to $Y\cap Cl_X(A)$. For example with $X= \mathbb R$ with the usual topology, and $Y=[0,1),$ we have $Cl_Y((1/2,0))=[1/2,0).$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The subspace topology on $Y$ is defined by

$$\{Y\cap U \colon U \in \tau\}$$

So if $F$ is closed in $Y$, then $Y\setminus F$ is open in $Y$. By the subspace topology,

$$Y\setminus F = Y \cap U$$ where $U\in \tau$. This implies

$$F=Y\setminus(Y\setminus F)=Y \setminus (Y \cap U) = Y \setminus U = Y \cap U^c $$

As $U \in \tau$, therefore $U^c \in \tau^c$.

I'll let you show the converse part.

Answer (score 1):

Definition: $O \subseteq Y$ is $\tau_Y$-open iff $O = O' \cap Y$, where $O' \in \tau_X$.

So $F \subseteq Y$ is $\tau_Y$ closed  iff

$Y \setminus F$ is $\tau_Y$ open iff $Y \setminus F = O' \cap Y$, where $O' \in \tau_X$

Now,  $Y \setminus F = O' \cap Y$ iff $(X \setminus O') \cap Y = F $; this follows by a simple set theory argument, or draw the Venn diagram to convince yourself.

So closed sets in $Y$ are exactly the intersections of closed sets in $X$ with $Y$.

Answer (score 1):

If $\langle X,\tau\rangle$ is a topological space, $Y\subseteq X$ and $\iota:Y\to X$ denotes the inclusion then it is not difficult to verify that the collection $\tau_Y=\{\iota^{-1}(U)\mid U\in\tau\}$ is a topology on $Y$.

(Observe here that actually $\iota^{-1}(U)=Y\cap U$.)

It is the so-called **subspace topology** on $Y$ inherited from $X$.

It can be recognized as the coarsest topology on $Y$ such that $\iota:Y\to X$ is continuous.

S0 a set $F\subseteq Y$ is closed w.r.t. the subspace topology iff it can be written it as $F=\iota^{-1}(U)^c$ where $U\in\tau$.

Then on base of the evident equality $\iota^{-1}(U)^c=\iota^{-1}(U^c)=Y\cap U^c$ we find that $F\subseteq Y$ is closed w.r.t. the subspace topology iff it can be written as $Y\cap H$ where $H=U^c$ is a closed set in the original topology.